# Uploading file and inserting information to custom columns to a Sharepoint Library using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm learning powershell to create a script that uploads files to a sub-site library inside SharePoint. I managed to get it working and uploading .doc files to my library, however I also want fill in any metadata specified in additional columns with the file at the same time. I'm not using the SharePoint snap-in and instead using the webclient functions. Here is the simple powershell script

```
# create the Variable Path and Pass the source folder path

$path = "THE FILE"

# create the Variable destination and pass the URL of the SharePoint List
$destination = "SharePoint SubSite"

# Store the current user default credentials in the Variable Credentials
$credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials;

# Create the object of the Webclient 

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;

$webclient.Credentials = $credentials;

$webclient.UploadFile($destination + “/” + "Filename", “PUT”, TheFile)
```

This code works however I don't know how to use the webclient functions to pass metadata to custom columns. When the file is uploaded I noticed the only first two columns are updated but the custom fields are left blank.

If this is even possible let me know.

Much thanks for your help

Comment: Does your script run on the server itself?

Comment: No I don't have access to the server. I only have access to the intranet. I'm trying to do it client side,

Comment: Instead of updating metadata property from powershell use designer workflow there you can get the property and upload it in the custom column. Is your documents using the same template ? If yes then add the same file in Forms folder of same document library, then enter the template path in list advance settings and map each field with custom columns. And then your custom columns will get automatically updated once you add the file. No workflow or script is required :)

Comment: Hmmm.. The idea of the script that I want to write is to upload a bunch of files and parse the file name and put the information in the custom columns all at once. Instead of uploading 1 file at a time and typing in the column information for over 100+ files which would take hours.

Comment: You can still rely on the listdata.svc webservice, or the legacy list.asmx web service, to set the metadata after the actual upload.

Answer (score 1):

Basically three options are available here (it is assumed SharePoint 2010 is used):

- consume SharePoint 2010 REST interface
- consume SharePoint Web Services
- consume [SharePoint 2010 Client SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786)

### How to consume SharePoint 2010 REST Interface via PowerShell

The following function demonstrates how to perform CRUD operations using SharePoint 2010 REST interface:

```
<#
.Synopsis
    Sends an HTTP or HTTPS request to a SharePoint 2010 REST-compliant web service.
.DESCRIPTION
    This function sends an HTTP or HTTPS request to a Representational State
    Transfer (REST)-compliant ("RESTful") SharePoint Online web service.
.EXAMPLE
   Invoke-SPRestMethod -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Projects"
#>
Function Invoke-SPRestRequest()
{
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$WebUrl,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[String]$ListName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[int]$ItemId,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[String]$QueryOptions,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestMethod]$Method = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestMethod]::Get,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[System.Net.ICredentials]$Credentials,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[String]$Payload,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[String]$ETag,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[String]$XHTTPMethod,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[System.String]$Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose",

[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[String]$ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose"
)

    #Construct Endpoint URL 
    $endpointUrl = $WebUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + $ListName
    if($ItemId){
        $endpointUrl = $endpointUrl + "(" + $ItemId + ")"
    }
    if($QueryOptions){
        $endpointUrl = $endpointUrl + $QueryOptions
    }


    $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    if($Credentials) {
        $client.Credentials = $Credentials
    } 
    $client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
    $client.Headers.Add("Content-Type",$ContentType)
    $client.Headers.Add("Accept",$Accept)
    if($Method -eq "Get") {
        $result = $client.DownloadString($endpointUrl) | ConvertFrom-Json
    }
    elseif ($Method -eq "Post") {
        if($ETag) { 
           $client.Headers.Add("If-Match", $ETag)
        } 
        if($XHTTPMethod) { 
            $client.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", $XHTTPMethod)
        }
        if($Payload) {
             $client.UploadString($endpointUrl,$Method,$Payload) 
        }
        else {
             $client.UploadString($endpointUrl,$Method) 
        }   
    }
    $client.Dispose()
    return $result
}
```

Gist: [Invoke-SPRestRequest.ps1](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/3cb8934adb9988dab6cf)

### Example

The following example demonstrates how to upload a file into SharePoint 2010 and set metadata properties. It consists of:

1. Upload a file operation
2. Find the uploaded list item associated with uploaded file
3. Update list item properties

Code:

```
$UserName = "username"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$WebUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/project"
$FolderUrl = "/project/Shared Documents/Archive"


Function Find-ListItem([string]$WebUrl,[System.Net.ICredentials]$Credentials,[string]$ListName,[string]$QueryOptions)
{
    $result = Invoke-SPRestRequest -WebUrl $WebUrl -ListName $ListName -QueryOptions $QueryOptions -Credentials $Credentials 
    return $result.d.results
}



Function Update-ListItem([string]$WebUrl,[System.Net.ICredentials]$Credentials,[string]$ListName,[int]$ItemId)
{
    $itemPayload = @{ 
       "DocumentStatusValue" = "Close"; 
    } | ConvertTo-Json
    Invoke-SPRestRequest -WebUrl $WebUrl -ListName $ListName -ItemId $ItemId -Credentials $Credentials -Method Post -Payload $itemPayload -ETag "*" -XHTTPMethod "MERGE"
}


Function Upload-File([string]$WebUrl,[System.Net.ICredentials]$Credentials,[string]$FolderUrl, [string]$FileName)
{
    $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    #$client.Credentials = $Credentials
    $client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")

    $siteUri = New-Object Uri($WebUrl)
    $fileUri = New-Object Uri($siteUri, ($FolderUrl + "/" + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($FileName)))

    $result = $client.UploadFile($fileUri, "PUT", $FileName)
    $client.Dispose()
}




#1.Upload a File
Upload-File -WebUrl $WebUrl -FolderUrl $FolderUrl  -FileName "D:\tmp\SharePoint User Guide.docx"

#2.Find an associated List Item for a File 
$query = "?`$filter=Path eq '" + $FolderUrl + "'"
$ListItem = Find-ListItem -WebUrl $WebUrl  -ListName "Documents" -QueryOptions $query

#3.Update List Item properties
Update-ListItem -WebUrl $WebUrl -ListName "Documents" -ItemId $ListItem.Id
```

### References

[SharePoint Foundation REST Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521587(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help this i am new to this bit and it seems a bit confusing, if you had time could I get a bit of a walk through of the code? Focusing on how this rest crud operations work, then how the power shell code is used to find and insert data into a specific column in a sharepoint libary after it's been uploaded. I tried to run this code but i am not sure where to plug in the information into the right variables to get it to function. If there is anything additional I need to read about some of the functions in order to communicate what I'm asking let me know.